# Javascript google analytics in self-executing anonymous function

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to write some custom javascript inside a self-executing anonymous function. This custom javascript needs to interact with the global Google Analytics `ga` function that is created when the Google Analytics library is loaded. The following code is in the `<head>` of the page loading the library:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
</script>
```

At the bottom of the page, my custom javascript is loaded. This is the code:

```
(function($, MutationObserver, shippingMethods, ga) {

    function triggerPageview(path) {
        ga('send', 'pageview', path);
    }

})(jQuery, MutationObserver, shippingMethods, ga);
```

What I am finding is that the current code does not successfully trigger a pageview. The pageview only gets triggered if I remove ga from the arguments, like this:

```
(function($, MutationObserver, shippingMethods) {

    function triggerPageview(path) {
        ga('send', 'pageview', path);
    }

})(jQuery, MutationObserver, shippingMethods);
```

The code above works, the first example doesn't. I'm assuming this is me misunderstanding how these arguments to a self-executing anonymous function are supposed to work. I'm guessing that when the self-executing function is executed, the value of `ga` is some value before the external Google Analytics library is loaded. However, I thought that after the library loads, and `ga` is updated, that the `ga` inside my function would also be updated. Is this not true?

I logged the value of `ga` before the pageview is triggered, to compare, first with `ga` passed in:

```
(function($, MutationObserver, shippingMethods, ga) {

    function triggerPageview(path) {
        console.log(ga);
        ga('send', 'pageview', path);
    }

})(jQuery, MutationObserver, shippingMethods, ga);
```

This logs:

```
ƒ (){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)}
```

Then without the `ga` argument:

```
(function($, MutationObserver, shippingMethods) {

    function triggerPageview(path) {
        console.log(ga);
        ga('send', 'pageview', path);
    }

})(jQuery, MutationObserver, shippingMethods);
```

This logs:

```
ƒ (a){J(1);Z.D.apply(Z,[arguments])}
```

So, it seems I am definitely misunderstanding something. Can someone explain what's going on here? What is the "proper" way to refer to a global within custom code like I am showing?

When I pass `ga` into my function, is it making a "copy" of the current value of `ga`, rather than referring to the global `ga` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I answered my own question. Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/how-analyticsjs-works

I think Google Analytics is redefining the `ga` command after the library loads. So my function still references the originally defined `ga` method, but the global `ga` has been redefined. In this case it seems it would be best to not pass the `ga` argument, and instead just always refer to `window.ga`.